# how to assert a dataframe value is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I assert a specific Pandas row/column value is nan ?  I tried to assert a value from the iloc DataFrame value and from converting the Pandas DataFrame to Numpy array.  It seems as if I can feed values in as np.nan but I can't test individual values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame([
    dict(id=1, color='red'),
    dict(id=2, color='blue'),
    dict(id=3, color=np.nan),
])

assert df.iloc[0, 1] == 'red'  # True
assert df.iloc[1, 1] == 'blue' # True

# Assertion fails
assert df.iloc[2, 1] == np.nan 

# Assertion fails
assert df.to_numpy()[2][1] == np.nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want

```
assert np.isnan(df.iloc[2, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick:

```
assert df.iloc[2, [1]].isna().any()
```

Let's use pd.Series method isna.  We can bracket the column to force a return of a signle element pandas series.

another way is to use either math.isnan or np.isnan.

```
import math

assert math.isnan(df.iloc[2, 1])
```